# Convert a column of str into a column of datetime

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a huge column named Date of str with this format: year-month-day 
and I want to convert it into a DateTime type

Can someone help me, please :)

Comment: please provide sample data.

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 0):

this should fix your problem

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go :)

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2018-07-17', '%Y-%m-%d')
```